# How to upload my android application to galaxy tab

Tags: android

Could anyone tell me how to upload/install the android application, which I created with eclipse, to galaxy tab? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can either create an .apk file (as mentioned by Blumer) or you could just plug-in the device into your computer through USB and use Run function in Eclipse - it will automatically install and run the program. If Eclipse doesn't find your Galaxy Tab, then chances are you don't have drivers for the device installed. On my computer (Windows 7 32bit) I had to install Samsung Kies before it worked. As far as I know it works directly out of the box on MacOS. I don't know how it works in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

One quick and easy way is to make your .apk file available at a URL and then visit that URL in the Galaxy Tab's browser.